# Microsoft Outlook for Mac 2011 "Not Responding" after upgrade to Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: mac, ms-office, macos

I'm experiencing issue with my `Microsoft Outlook for Mac 2011` after upgrading to `Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan`.

`Activity Monitor` and/or `Force Quit Applications` shows `Microsoft Outlook` is `Not Responding`.

I found following knowledge base article:

[Outlook for Mac 2011 on OS X 10.11 hangs during account sync operation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3098396)

Microsoft's workaround:

> To work around this issue, run Outlook for Mac 2011 on Mac OS X
>   Yosemite (version 10.10) or an earlier version.

Is there anything else I can do?

---

FIX: [Microsoft Office for Mac 2011 14.5.6 update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3098229)

Comment: Same here, it did not work. I've also removed "Contacts" and "Mail & Messages" options from the Spotlight configuration in System Preferences (suggested in other posts) without success. I'm going to have to use Time Machine to restore a backup on OS 10.10 prior to the install of El Capitan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has an update to fix the problem now.

For more information, check out this knowledge base article documenting the problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3098396

> Shortly after you start Microsoft Outlook for Mac 2011 on Mac OS X El Capitan (version 10.11), Outlook hangs when it tries to sync with the server. The Spinning Wait cursor is displayed, and the application status is displayed as "Not Responding."
>
> [...]
>
> This issue occurs in Outlook for Mac 2011 version 14.5.5 and earlier versions when they are running on Mac OS X El Capitan (version 10.11).

To install the fix, you can either:

- Open Outlook and click Check for Updates on the help menu (if your outlook freezes before you can update, you can create a blank profile temporarily by ALT-Clicking on the Outlook icon),
- Download the update package at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49183

Answer (score 0):

Try following the mentioned steps in this [Outlook for Mac 2011 crashes or hangs at startup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2409331) from Microsoft Support:

I have read somewhere that Step #2 *should* resolve the issue you're having:

> **Step 2: Open Outlook 2011 without running schedules or trying to connect to a mail server**
>
> Opening Outlook without running schedules or trying to connect to a
>   mail server is a way to determine whether the issue is related to the
>   account settings or pending send/receive actions. To do this, follow
>   these steps:
>
> - Press the Shift key and then click the Outlook icon on the Dock. This prevents Outlook from sending or receiving mail.
> - Quit Outlook.
> - Open Outlook.
>
> If the issue continues to occur, go to the next step.

Comment: This did _NOT_ worked for *me*, can someone else confirm as well please?

Comment: It worked for me.  I had to do it twice.  Otherwise, try following the complete steps from the Microsoft Support article linked to in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> while opening Outlook, this will only stop Outlook from syncing with your internet account (email).

This does not solve the problem, alas!

If you press Sync button, Outlook will freeze/crash.